# Cannot access elements inside of an iframe element

Tags: javascript

I've been facing an issue while trying to access an element inside the document rendered through an Iframe element.

When i access the parent node of the Iframe element you can see the embedded document within the iframe element

Log of the parent:

[image: log of the parent]

But when i specifically try to access the iframe element you can see the embedded document becomes empty

Log of the iframe element:

[image: log of the iframe element]

I want to access a button that exists within the iframe element and because of this issue i am not able to do so.

Comment: Is the iframe content from your own domain?

Comment: no it's not, does that mean it is because of cross-site scripting protection?

Comment: Yes, you cannot access the content of a cross domain iframe

Answer (score -1):

I think what you got is Cors (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).
The server your got the iframe from refuse others to load theire resources